# Reform and refine the regex of the URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to break down the URL of the website with regex. The URL is similar as follows:

```
https://product.testing.com/intro/index.aspx?source=newsletter&product=watch&brand=rolex
```

The regex that I used is as follows:

```
(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(product\.)(testing\.)(com\/)(.*)(\?|\?)([^=]\w+(?=&))
```

The first question is, I would like to chop the part after aspx? into pieces i.e source=newsletter, product=watch etc, and the code does not work for the last part, What did I do wrong and how should I change?

The second question is, The domain name part is a kind of hard coding...how can I make it better and more flexible e.g can be applied to `https://contact.testing.com/contactoursales/index.aspx?`

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: what if url does not contain any parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) package, instead of a regex to parse an URL.

```
const URL = require('url');

const url = 'https://product.testing.com/intro/index.aspx?source=newsletter&product=watch&brand=rolex';

// Pass true to parse the querystring too
const parsed = URL.parse(url, true);
```

Which will output:

```
Url {
  protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'product.testing.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'product.testing.com',
  hash: null,
  search: '?source=newsletter&product=watch&brand=rolex',
  query: { source: 'newsletter', product: 'watch', brand: 'rolex' },
  pathname: '/intro/index.aspx',
  path: '/intro/index.aspx?source=newsletter&product=watch&brand=rolex',
  href: 'https://product.testing.com/intro/index.aspx?source=newsletter&product=watch&brand=rolex' }
```

> I would like to chop the part after aspx? into pieces i.e
>   source=newsletter, product=watch etc, and the code does not work for
>   the last part, What did I do wrong and how should I change?

Passing `true` as second parameter to `url.parse` will parse the querystring for you.

```
console.log(params.query);

/* {
    source: 'newsletter',
    product: 'watch',
    brand: 'rolex'
} */
```

If you're not using node.js you can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to use `url` package on the browser.

```
webpack url-parser.js -o url-parser.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, The solution is great! But as I understand it's node.js right? If I want to use the most traditional way in javascript to extract the information like the code before, how can I make it?

Comment: You're welcome. you can use it on the browser as the last part of the answer explains. This module is written in pure Javascript so it can be used on the browser. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @PakHangLeung there's no traditional way, you should parse the URL, and either you build a parser yourself, or use one that is working & documented, like `url` package from node.